# NextJs - Same route name for different action

Tags: routes, next.js, action

I want to know, can we use the same route name for a different action?
e.g. product/id for get, edit, and delete data.

it's possible in NextJs? I want to achieve the same routing system as Laravel where it can use one name for different actions based on the form method

Comment: What do you mean under action? something line /blog/post /blog/post2? Or to show different page content on the same page?

Comment: what I meant is usually when we want to create a route we give the route path like e.g. product/edit/:id for edit page and product/delete/:id for delete page. what I want to know is it's possible to make a route path with the path? where each route path is doing different tasks? e.g. product/:id for edit page and product/:id for delete page. I have seen Laravel can do this but not sure in NextJs because I'm still learning.

Comment: here is the example for the route in Laravel https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers the show, update, and destroy action took the same route path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, you can have nested routing with Next.js

**Part 1:**
Folder structure (details [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)):

**pages**/product/delete/[id].js (or .tsx)

Behavior:
When you access [your_domain]/product/delete/433 your customer will be redirected to the `page` of deleting, you will capture your `433` value on this page. If you need action, you can just create [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) and call **delete** method. (for example, on button click)

So, your task is sptitted for 2 steps:

1. Create a API route
2. Create a page
3. Fetch data from route to page. (Use this [lib](https://swr.vercel.app/) for client-side rendering, or [getServerProps/getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation))

Also, you might create some `"middleware"` to properly connect `DB` to your project.

P.S. there are no controllers such as "Controllers" in laravel, you create pages and pages contact `DB` via `API calls`.

**Example:**

*/pages/weather/[city].tsx*

```
import useSWR from 'swr'

const Post = ({cityName, data}) => {
  
  //replace with your API
  //if you like to get data on client-side
  //you can set inverval of refresh, real-time data
  const {data: cityData, error: errorData} = useSWR(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=&q=${cityName}&aqi=no`, { refreshInterval: 500 })
  if (!cityData)
  return <div>Loading</div>
  if (cityData){
  return (
        <div>
            <p>Details for city: {cityName}</p>
            <p>Data via client side fetch </p>
            <pre>
                <code>
                {JSON.stringify(cityData, null, 2)}
                </code>
            </pre>
            <p>Data via server-side</p>
            <pre>
                <code>
                {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
                </code>
            </pre>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    //if you like to fetch data on server side
    //laoded only ONCE page is requested (static)
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=&q=${context.params.city}&aqi=no`);
    const data = await res.json();
    return {
        props: {
            cityName: context.params.city,
            data: data
        }
    }
}
export default Post
```

So, If you signin in weatherAPI and add your key (`?key=`) in API request route, it will render your page, showing the weather in city you have defined/ (examples: /weather/london; /weather/berlin)